# Comparing Two Dataframe & populate value same as vlookup

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dataframe. Now i want to compare two dataframe.in First dataframe i want to insert column at the last and based on common record betwn two dataframe i want to populate value (same as vlookup function into the newly added column).i want to repeat the same in other sheet also in first dataframe
during export first dataframe should contain all the existing column+newly added column & values to be populated into newly added column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

df=pd.read_excel(r"stored xlsb file",engine='pyxlsb',sheet_name='sheet name')
print(df)

df1=pd.read_csv(r"stored csv file",sep=',')
print(df1)

merged_df=pd.merge(df,df1,on='Unique id',how='left')
print(merged_df)
today=datetime.today().strftime('%d-%b')
print(today)
df[today] =merged_df['value from the column to be populated'].fillna(0)
print(merged_df)
merged_df.to_csv(r"storing location")
```

i was expecting if i export df it should contain existing column+today column and value from column to be populated should be into the today column. and same i want to repeat in other sheet where i want other column to be populated.